# how to get a file from the IIS site folder in ASP.NET Core web API app

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I need to create an Excel File based in a excel file template where I add teh content that feed a chart.
In my web API proyect I put the template.xlsx in the folder of my webAPI project and the I access to it using this code

```
public async Task<XLWorkbook> PrintPlanning(PrintDataVM data)
{
  string fileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Plantilla.xlsx";


  using (XLWorkbook wb=new XLWorkbook(fileName))
  {
    var ws = wb.Worksheet("Planificado");
    var wsGrafica = wb.Worksheet("Grafica");
```

But now I have publishe my webAPI in web site in IIS inside this folder in the server "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fysegplannerAPI" and here I have put the template.xlsx

And now I don't know how to access to this file because obviously Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Plantilla.xlsx" does not work

I have read this:[IIS access](https://www.jauernig-it.de/asp-net-coreiis-serving-content-from-a-file-share/)

But I do not fully understand. If I start my app and I debug env.WebRootPath is null. once you have published in IIS what value it is supposed to have?

And I don't understand what RequestPatch means either

And finally I don't know how I can access these values from the code of my controllers or my repositories

Any idea Please?

regards

Comment: could you please share which library you are using to get the excel file?

Comment: Hi I'm using ClosedXML

Comment: does Plantilla.xlsx is existed at the location?

Comment: Yes it is. I have the file in the folder of the webApp published in IIS.